# Facebook share window when you “Like” a page getting cutoff

Tags: html, css, facebook, firefox, facebook-like

I am trying to add the FB like to my website.  The like seems to work ok.  However, when someone clicks the Like button (using Firefox on Mac Lion) a Share box appears which is show cutoff on my page.  Ideally I would like the share box to fully appear so that visitors can share their like.  If this is not possible then getting rid of the share box all together just leaving the "Like".

Here is how it looks:

[facebook like http://www.sofiaandluis.com/public/facebook_like.png](http://www.sofiaandluis.com/public/facebook_like.png)

Here is the code:
HTML

```
<div class="column-area">
    <div class="suscribe-social">
        <div class="up make-word-breakable">
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>(function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxx";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
            <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pagename" data-send="false" data-width="300" data-show-faces="true" data-font="verdana"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="down make-word-breakable"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.column-area {
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.127659574%;
}
.suscribe-social {
    border: 1px solid #E4E4E1;
    margin: 5px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.suscribe-social .up {
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.make-work-breakable {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it to work.  I removed the class

```
.fb-like iframe {
    width: 290px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen anything that indicates that that's configurable through the FB api, but I do believe this should work:

```
.fb-like {
    height: 20px;  // I think that's the button height, you might need to adjust
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The comment box will still get loaded, it'll just be hidden. No idea if any sort of complications might arise there, though I'd doubt it.

Comment: Hey @ultranaut, I tried doing that but it didn't work.  I also tried doing overflow:visible for this same class to no avail.  Any other suggestions?...  I am surprised this would be this complicated.  Thanks

Comment: Ah ok, I see, with the overflow hidden I can hide the box.  That would work.  Any idea on what I could do so that it fully shows?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your code? It's hard to say without seeing it in action. When you say it didn't work, does that mean it showed up the same as before you added that?

Comment: That all depends on what else is happening on the page, like I said it's hard to say without seeing code.

Comment: -1 on me for reading comprehension, I totally zeroed in on how to hide it, and missed your link.

Comment: He, no problem, thanks for your quick help, without it I would not have been able to figure it out... so thanks @ultranaut!

Answer (score 1):

I think that FB box gets cutted because some parent element has "overflow: hidden" property.

This property may prevent FB box to exceed the size of that parent element.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty old but I'd like to add another answer on here that doesn't involve having an `!important` on our css. Which is--let's be honest--just doesn't look right.

```
.fb-like iframe { max-width:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.fb-like span{
overflow:visible 
!important; 
width:450px !important; 
margin-right:-375px;
}
```

this should work.....good luck

Answer (score 0):

Also, position:absolute; works on the holder element of the button.